User "Unknown" dialog appears on my desktop
My MATE on arch has been running for four years without unusual problems. But today, restarting after a cold shutdown from the terminal, the desktop throws up a dialog titled "About Unknown".
There is a static field shouting 'UNKNOWN' and static field with my desktop username and an input field through which I can change my password.
Update after comment by ctx
This is not a modal dialog. I can close it and continue as usual.
I start the session from the terminal after system startup. I login as myself then sudo systemctl start lightdm
This is how I've been doing it for years. There are no recent updates to any MATE components or gnupg.

Can you login on another TTY?

@ctx I'll clarify in the original.
